# ¿Cómo manejar metaCharacters en un input y que los cuente como uno solo en el maxlength?

Tags: javascript

Tengo un `<input>` donde debo aceptar un máximo de 10 caracteres, es decir, tener un `maxlength` de 10 caracteres, pero dentro de este debo ingresar ***Meta Caracteres*** (especie de código por ejemplo `[:heart:])` que mi página interpreta como un icono de corazón, por ejemplo. También puedo ingresar texto y demás.

**El problema:**

Cuando coloco un código (o *Meta Caracteres*), por ejemplo `[:heart:]` ya el `<input>` me cuenta **9** caracteres! y solo puedo escribir uno más y ya.

**Mi pregunta:**

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que este código (o *Meta Caracteres*) me lo cuente como uno solo y así poder ingresar 9 caracteres más?

Comment: Tienes que quitar el maximo y gestionarlo tu en el evento onKeypress contando tu en javascript esos 10 caracteres (vas sumando 1 pero si la letra que encuentras es '[' seguido de ':' no cuentas hasta que encuentres ':' seguido de ']')

Comment: haz la validacion despues de interpolar/transformar el emoii como texto unicode. Lo estas haciendo antes.

Comment: te deje un código que maneja `metacharacters`, Saludos!! ;))...

Answer (score 3):

Aquí te dejo un código para manejar meta caracteres y que el largo del `String` no exceda los indicados en la función, puedes manejar varios meta caracteres colocandolos en la matriz `meta[]`, tales como: **black (spades ♠), red (hearts ♥), blue (diamonds ♦) y green (clubs ♣)**.
.

Ejemplo:

```js
function meta(event,maxlength) {
 var el  = event.target,

  // MetaCharacters: black (spades ♠), red (hearts ♥), blue (diamonds ♦)
  // and green (clubs ♣)
  meta = {0:{code:"[:spades:]"  , char:"♠"}, // Elementos++
          1:{code:"[:heart:]"   , char:"♥"},
          2:{code:"[:diamonds:]", char:"♦"},
          3:{code:"[:clubs:]"   , char:"♣"},
          length:4,       // Numero de Elementos
          maxlength:12},  // length del Elemento con máximo tamaño
  len = 0,
  warning = false,
  ss  = el.selectionStart,
  se  = el.selectionEnd,
  key = event.key;

 if(key.length != 1) {
  key = "";
  if(event.key == "Backspace") {
   ss = el.selectionStart - 1;
  } else if(event.key == "Delete") {
   se = se + 1;
  }
 }
 val = el.value.substr(0,ss) + key + el.value.substr(se);
 for (var x = meta.maxlength; x > 0; x--) {
  for (var y = meta.length-1; y >= 0; y--) {
   if (meta[y].code.length >= x) {
    tmp = val.split(meta[y].code.substr(0,x)).join(meta[y].char);
    if (x != meta[y].code.length && tmp != val)
     warning = true;
    val = tmp;
   };
  };
 }; 
 if (warning || val.length>maxlength) {
  el.classList.add("warning");
 } else {
  el.classList.remove("warning");
 }
 console.log(val);
 if (key && val.length>maxlength)
  event.preventDefault();
};
```

```css
.warning {
 color:red;
}
```

```html
<input onkeydown="meta(event,10)">
```

Espero esto te sirva, Saludos!! ;))...

Answer (score 1):

Prueba esto. No diferencia entre mayúsculas y minúsculas. Se puede copiar y pegar:

```js
// Javascript
function maxlength() {
    var txtIni=document.getElementById("input1").value;
    var txt=txtIni;
    while(txt.length
        - (txt.match(/\[:heart:\]/gi) || []).length
        - (txt.match(/\[:heart:/gi) || []).length
        - (txt.match(/\[:heart/gi) || []).length
        - (txt.match(/\[:hear/gi) || []).length
        - (txt.match(/\[:hea/gi) || []).length
        - (txt.match(/\[:he/gi) || []).length
        - (txt.match(/\[:h/gi) || []).length
        - (txt.match(/\[:/gi) || []).length
        - (txt.match(/\[:foo:\]/gi) || []).length
        - (txt.match(/\[:foo:/gi) || []).length
        - (txt.match(/\[:foo/gi) || []).length
        - (txt.match(/\[:fo/gi) || []).length
        - (txt.match(/\[:f/gi) || []).length>10){
        txt=txt.slice(0, -1);
    }
    if(txt!==txtIni)
        document.getElementById("input1").value=txt;
};
document.getElementById("input1").onkeyup = maxlength;
function recortar() {
    var txtIni=document.getElementById("input1").value;
    var txt=txtIni;
    while(txt.length
        - (txt.match(/\[:heart:\]/gi) || []).length*('[:heart:]'.length-1)
        - (txt.match(/\[:foo:\]/gi) || []).length*('[:foo:]'.length-1)>10){
        txt=txt.slice(0, -1);
    }
    if(txt!==txtIni)
        document.getElementById("input1").value=txt;
};
document.getElementById("input1").onblur = recortar;
// JQuery
$('#input2').on('keyup', function () {
    var txtIni=$(this).val();
    var txt=txtIni;
    while(txt.length
        - (txt.match(/\[:heart:\]/gi) || []).length
        - (txt.match(/\[:heart:/gi) || []).length
        - (txt.match(/\[:heart/gi) || []).length
        - (txt.match(/\[:hear/gi) || []).length
        - (txt.match(/\[:hea/gi) || []).length
        - (txt.match(/\[:he/gi) || []).length
        - (txt.match(/\[:h/gi) || []).length
        - (txt.match(/\[:/gi) || []).length
        - (txt.match(/\[:foo:\]/gi) || []).length
        - (txt.match(/\[:foo:/gi) || []).length
        - (txt.match(/\[:foo/gi) || []).length
        - (txt.match(/\[:fo/gi) || []).length
        - (txt.match(/\[:f/gi) || []).length>10){
        txt=txt.slice(0, -1);
    }
    if(txt!==txtIni)
        $(this).val(txt);
}).on('blur',function(){
    var txtIni=$(this).val();
    var txt=txtIni;
    while(txt.length
        - (txt.match(/\[:heart:\]/gi) || []).length*('[:heart:]'.length-1)
        - (txt.match(/\[:foo:\]/gi) || []).length*('[:foo:]'.length-1)>10){
        txt=txt.slice(0, -1);
    }
    if(txt!==txtIni)
        $(this).val(txt);
});
```

```html
<script         src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input id="input1" type="text" style="width: 500px;">
<input id="input2" type="text" style="width: 500px;">
```

Saludos.

Comment: intento evaluar tu respuesta de la siguiente manera: coloco 1234, luego retrocedo hasta el 2 e intento ingresar [:heart:] pero me falla.

Comment: He corregido ese problema en concreto pero auditar el campo caracter a caracter siempre tendrá inconvenientes si el usuario realiza modificaciones en el interior de la cadena. Yo desestimaría por completo esta opción y dejaría solo la validación final del campo con el evento blur.

Comment: Intenta determinar donde esta el cursor del `input` con la propiedad **selectionStart** y **selectionEnd**, así resolverás el problema en donde esta insertando el texto. igualmente, siempre tendrá que validar el `<input>` con el evento **onChange** para determinar si lo escrito cumple con los requerimientos, revisa mi respuesta.